# They vs it–which to use here?

Tags: grammaticality, singular-vs-plural

At the restaurant I had X and Y. **They** were out of this world!

At the restaurant I had X and Y. **It** was out of this world!

X and Y are two separate dishes. Now in the first sentence, the usage of **they** seems fine and correct. But in the second one, the usage of **it** to describe two different dishes does not. But, if **it**, instead of meaning, two dishes, meant the whole eating experience, then that makes the sentence grammatically correct in regard to the previous statement again, right?

Comment: Yes - you can use whichever you want, depending on whether you mean 'those dishes' or 'the whole experience'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are valid but have slightly different meanings.

“They” means you had two experiences, one of X and one of Y, and each was “out of this world”.

“It” means a single experience of X and Y together, which might not be “out of this world” if experienced separately.